# What is the limit of $\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0,1)} {8 + y^2\over{x^2 + xy}}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

What is the limit of $\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0,1)} {8 + y^2\over{x^2 + xy}}$ ?

My attempt to find the limit:

$\lim \limits_{x = 0 \: y \to 1} {8 + y^2\over{x^2 + xy}} = 
\lim \limits_{x = 0 \: y \to 1} {8 + y^2\over{0 + 0}} = 
\lim \limits_{x = 0 \: y \to 1} {8 + y^2\over{0}} => undefined$

$\lim \limits_{y = 1 \: x \to 0} {8 + y^2\over{x^2 + xy}} = 
\lim \limits_{y = 1 \: x \to 0} {8 + 1\over{x^2 + x}} = 
\lim \limits_{y = 1 \: x \to 0} {9\over{x^2 + x}}= \infty$

Therefore, the limit of $\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0,1)} {8 + y^2\over{x^2 + xy}}$ does not exist.

Comment: As far as I know the limit should be the same at least from any direction. The two horizontal directions, ie $y=1$, $x \to 0^+$, and $y=1$, $x \to 0^-$, are $\infty$ but with different signs. Btw the "undefined" part is useless I guess, It's just undefined, so what? It is not in the domain of definition, it says nothing since it is left apart.

Comment: irrespective of the direction, the denominator always $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes but it's like $1/x$, there is no unique limit in $0$.

Comment: The first (undefined) limit is not correct, because your function is not defined for $x=0$ and any $y$. But your idea is OK, try to work it out with @Maffred suggestion.